# Why does 'install-info' keep warning me about "lilypond"?

Tags: apt

I was trying to install nasm this morning when suddenly I got this message. What's happening here? What causes the message to appear?

```
install-info: warning: no info dir entry in `/usr/share/info/lilypond-learning.info.gz'
install-info: warning: no info dir entry in `/usr/share/info/music-glossary.info.gz'
install-info: warning: no info dir entry in `/usr/share/info/lilypond-changes.info.gz'
install-info: warning: no info dir entry in `/usr/share/info/lilypond-essay.info.gz'
install-info: warning: no info dir entry in `/usr/share/info/lilypond-notation.info.gz'
install-info: warning: no info dir entry in `/usr/share/info/lilypond-contributor.info.gz'
install-info: warning: no info dir entry in `/usr/share/info/lilypond-extending.info.gz'
install-info: warning: no info dir entry in `/usr/share/info/lilypond-snippets.info.gz'
install-info: warning: no info dir entry in `/usr/share/info/lilypond-usage.info.gz'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [**known bug**](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=648689) in the Lilypond package [and has not yet been fixed.](http://lists.debian.org/debian-tex-maint/2012/06/msg00172.html)

The warnings are annoying *but harmless*, so I'd just ignore them (or remove the `lilypond` package).

Hopefully this will be fixed by the time Ubuntu 12.10 is released